# Image Background not showing (Xamarin C#)

Tags: c#

I have been trying to implement a background image to my front- / sign in -page.

I've navigated to Resources -- Right-Clicked 'drawable' -- Add -- Add Existing -- BKR4.png
Afterwards I got in 'main' and did this:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:background="@drawable/BKR3" />
```

All I want is the picture to become the background. Nothing more. When I see my designer the picture is there, but as soon as I start emulating it only shows the default grey screen.
I havent coded in anything else in the project except that I showed u
I tried rescaling in all sorts of different sizes. 300 x 300, 450 x 854 and so on :(

Comment: Is the bundle action of your image set to AndroidResource?

Comment: Also, try to change build config from Debug to Release (or the other way around), rebuild and check - I remember seeing this bug...

Comment: Hi Michal Z, thanks for a fast reply!
No, the bundle action of my image is def not set to AndroidResource since I havent touched anything in my project except that piece I showed you. 
I might need to learn a bit more before jumping into this, cause I dont have a clue how I even set it to AndroidResource.. Daarn!

Comment: Click right on the image in your IDE, you will see it there

Comment: Got it! Yes it is set to AndroidResource and I tried changing debug to release with a rebuild. No luck.. hmm

Comment: Can you provide me with a full path to your image (inside the project)?

Comment: HOORAY.. I got it working! Thanks a lot. Appreciate it a lot!!

Comment: Cool! Please answer to your question and accept it as answer, so someone with similar problem can benefit from it :)